# Using the result of FROM-subquery in WHERE-subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

Question: since the FROM-clause is logically executed before the WHERE-clause, shouldn't it be possible to use the result of a FROM-subquery in a WHERE-subquery?

For example:

Suppose that the following table is defined in sqlite3:

```
create table MyTable(name, data1, data2, salary);
insert into MyTable values('J', 4, 8, 30);
insert into MyTable values('J', 8, 4, 30);
insert into MyTable values('J', 16, 16, 20);
insert into MyTable values('Dan', 32, 32, 25);
```

The following query aims, for each `name`, to output a single row with the largest `salary` for that `name`:

```
select name1 as name, data1, data2, salary
from (
    select rowid, name as name1, data1, data2, salary 
    from MyTable 
    where salary=(
        select max(salary) from MyTable where name=name1) 
    ) T
where rowid = (
    select max(rowid)
    from T
    where name1 = name);
```

However, sqlite3 gives the error:
Error: near line 11: no such table: T

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the result of a subquery multiple times, then use `with`, not a subquery:

```
with T as (
      select rowid, name as name1, data1, data2, salary 
      from MyTable 
      where salary = (select max(salary) from MyTable where name=name1) 
     ) 
select name1 as name, data1, data2, salary
from T
where rowid = (select max(rowid) from T where name1 = name);
```

The answer to your question is clearly "No".  SQLite does not allow what you want.  Nor does any other version of SQL.  The `FROM` clause defines table aliases that can be used to qualify columns, but these cannot be re-used in another `FROM` clause.  Note that the *columns* can be used in the `WHERE`, but not the "table".

Comment: FYI This is called a "Common table expression": https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: Unfortunately, until most recently, sqlite3 did not support the WITH-clause. Is there a workaround (besides creating a temporary table, which is not thread-safe unless I am missing an easy way to make it safe)?